# How to use for loop in weex ? like for (var x = 0; x < n; x++){} . The use case is : I want to render a box n times

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, weex

Given is the use case:-
I want to render a box n times. How to implement for loop from 0 to n in weex template.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <div class="box" ></div>
    <!--n times-->
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
  .box {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #BBB;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue has `v-for` directive:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   n: 10
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #BBB;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="box" v-for="i in n" :key="i"></div>
</div>
```

See also weex [example](http://dotwe.org/vue/368757f86e67b18e9695eb71be75e203)